# Direct Vent natural gas fireplace has shut off 3 times by itself

Tags: fireplace

I have a fairly new fireplace, we have used it a lot this season. 3 times the fireplace shut itself off. The fireplace would beep every few seconds. Hitting the off button on the remote - nothing. Hitting the on button on the remote, the fireplace starts up as normal. We have a CO detector in the room - no alarm.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The make and model of the fireplace would be helpful, as would a picture of the control system.

Comment: We a white mountain Tahoe traditional series 36" clean face premium millivolt fireplace #DVCP36BP30N.

Answer (score 1):

1)your system is not bringing in fresh air for combustion

2) your system is not getting rid of exhaust gasses

3) you have a faulty oxygen depletion sensor that is lying to your system and causing shut down

If you leave the box open does it operate properly? If yes rule out number 3

DO NOT OPERATE THIS WITH THE GLASS OPEN !!!! You and your family could lose your life.

After reading your comments I have a couple more suggestions

The vent pipe must be designed specifically for use in your model fireplace. These are two pipes in one. The inner pipe carries the hot exhaust air out of the fire box while the outer pipe brings in fresh out side air. If you have simply attached a single wall flue to the box your fresh and exhaust air are mixing. That is not good. It would lead to combustion issues. If you have  have a two chambered flue that that is designed for use on direct vent fireplaces installed you should be sure that a proper termination cap is installed outside the house where it exits. These have baffles that can minimize effects of wind on the operation of the air exchange.  A high wind cap for these systems is available. [Example](https://www.northlineexpress.com/5-x-8-simpson-directvent-pro-high-wind-termination-cap-58dva-vch-6407.html)
[image]

Comment: The fireplace is below grade - therefore we have a snorkel attached. Could the connection to the snorkel be causing the problem?

Comment: Kris, first of all thanks for your response. Could you give me more details about your #3 comment. What is the box door? Is it the glass?

Comment: Yes I’m talking about the glass. With it off the oxygen depletion sensor should not be triggered  if it still shuts off I would suspect the ODS is faulty. Not sure of your  specific model but these units bring in outside air for combustion  and exhaust the products of combustion to the outside as well. Is the snorkel designed by the manufacturer?

Comment: http://whitemountainhearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/31447-13-0617-DVP36FP3579.pdf.   Page 51 trouble shooting has a few suggestions

Comment: Just re reading your post it seems you have intermittent problem I was thinking constant. Do the shutdowns occur when it is very windy outside?

Comment: Yes, the shutdowns do occur when it is windy. We live in an area that is windy.

Comment: No,  the snorkel was not designed by the fireplace manufacturer

Comment: As Kris listed improper venting will cause this problem, it is possible your home is tightly constructed and the fresh air vent may be creating a slight negative pressure or not providing enough fresh air. I have not experienced this but have a contractor firend that mentioned this on 2 homes originally thinking it was electrical they ended up adding a wind block to the vent suggested by the mfg and that solved the issue in both cases.+

Comment: Will give it a try

Comment: Can you give any insight on where to get a wind block or how to attach it?

Comment: http://whitemountainhearth.com/support/dealer-locator/.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZz8hFcyeus